# Why this extension is purely inseparable.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, local-field

Let $E$ be a local field of characteristic $p>0$. Let $\varphi$ be the absolute Frobenius map on $E$. Then how to prove that the field extension $E/\varphi(E)$ is purely inseparable.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter that it is a local field. Each $a \in E$ is the root of the purely inseparable polynomial
$$(x-a)^p = x^p - a^p \in E^p [x]$$